# Scanning from a file into an array of Mallocated Structs? (c)

Tags: c

I'm having some trouble reading in data from a file into an array of memory allocated structs in c. My relevant code is as follows:

```
//Struct that holds the restaurant information
typedef struct
{
    char *name;
    char *food;
    double *price;
    int *rating;
}RESTAURANT;

//Function to get all the reviews from the file
void reviews()
{
    int numReviews, i;
    char tempBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; //hold the user input

    RESTAURANT *reviews; //create an array of structs

    FILE *inputFile; //file pointer

    inputFile = fopen(INPUT_FILE_NAME, "r"); //open the input file

    //Get the number of reviews from the top of the file
    fgets(tempBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE, inputFile);
    sscanf(tempBuffer, "%d", &numReviews);

    //Allocate enough space in the struct array for the number of reviews
    reviews = malloc(sizeof(*reviews)*numReviews);

    //Loop to allocate memory for each field in each struct
    for(i = 0; i < numReviews; i++)
    {
        reviews[i].name = malloc(sizeof(char *));
        reviews[i].food = malloc(sizeof(char *));
        reviews[i].price = malloc(sizeof(double *));
        reviews[i].rating = malloc(sizeof(int *));
    }

    //Loop to get each field for each struct from the file
    //And store it in the struct array at the correct struct 
    for(i = 0; i < numReviews; i++)
    {
        fscanf(inputFile, "%s", reviews[i].name);
        fscanf(inputFile, "%s", reviews[i].food);
        fscanf(inputFile, "%lf", reviews[i].price);
        fscanf(inputFile, "%d", reviews[i].rating);
    }
```

And the file at reviews.txt is:

```
4
Chili's
AmericanizedMexican
10.95
3
BurgerKing
American
4.50
2
IHOP
American
9.50
1
OliveGarden
AmericanizedItalian
11.00
4
```

Reading in Chili's and AmericanizedMexican works fine. But when I try to print the price or rating of Chili's the price always prints `0.0` and the rating is always some huge number over 1 million. What am I doing wrong here? I'm guessing it must be either something with allocating the memory or something with the way I'm meant to read it in.

Comment: Two things: first, are you writing the size of the strings before you write the actual strings? Because the strings are variably sized it looks like.  Second, you may want to use fread, fwrite, fopen, and fclose.  Read the man pages.

Comment: @Gophyr: OP uses `fopen` and probably also `fclose` in code that isn't shown. How will `fread` help here? The data is ASCII data and can be read with `fgets` and `fscanf`. `fread` is for data of known byte size. And in the code, nothing is written at all; it is about reading from a file.

Comment: `fread` and `fwrite` allow you to control size and number of the elements read/written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know, but storing scalar values like price and rating as allocated data via pointers seems strange. You can do that, but it adds a lot of allocation overhead. Remeber that you have to `free` everything that you have allocated.

Besides that, you got the allocation wrong:

```
    reviews[i].name = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    reviews[i].food = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    reviews[i].price = malloc(sizeof(double *));
    reviews[i].rating = malloc(sizeof(int *));
```

You allocate memory to hold something the size of a pointer. You must allocate memory that can hold the thing pointed to. A useful allocation pattern is:

```
    x = malloc(sizeof(*x));
```

for single values and

```
    x = malloc(count * sizeof(*x));
```

for arrays of length `count`. You do that already for `reviews`. Your strings, i.e. char arrays, should be such arrays. So you should allocate:

```
    reviews[i].name = malloc(MAX_LEN * sizeof(char));
    reviews[i].food = malloc(MAX_LEN * sizeof(char));
    reviews[i].price = malloc(sizeof(double));
    reviews[i].rating = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

where `MAX_LEN` is a more or less arbitrary limit that you must set and enforce. (For example, you should make sure that `fscanf` never writes more than ´MAX_LEN` characters to the buffer; that includes the trailing null character.)

Your treatment of the scalar values is awkward. I'd change the struct to

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    char *food;
    double price;      // Store values, not pointers
    int rating;        // Same here
} RESTAURANT;
```

Throw out the allocation and scan directly into these fields, using the address operator `&` to get a pointer:

```
    fscanf(inputFile, "%lf", &reviews[i].price);
    fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &reviews[i].rating);
```

Comment: Thank you, you fixed my problem. I had tried storing them as values without the allocation but I forgot to but the & during the scanning, silly me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

your problem is

```
for(i = 0; i < numReviews; i++)
    {
        reviews[i].name = malloc(sizeof(char *));
        reviews[i].food = malloc(sizeof(char *));
        reviews[i].price = malloc(sizeof(double *));
        reviews[i].rating = malloc(sizeof(int *));
    }
```

Here, sufficient memory is not allocated.

do this

```
for(i = 0; i < numReviews; i++)
    {
        reviews[i].name = malloc(128 *sizeof(char));
        reviews[i].food = malloc(128 *sizeof(char));
        reviews[i].price = malloc(sizeof(double));
        reviews[i].rating = malloc(sizeof(int));
    }
```

EDIT:

<sup>The value 128 is used for demonstration purpose only, just to point out the erroneous part in OP's code.</sup>

Comment: What if the name is bigger than 127?

Comment: Why 128? Just because?

Comment: @nouney  & @ Filipe  Well, that's just a hint.

Comment: My problem is not with the char allocation, that works fine, the problem is with the double/int. And taking away the *'s didn't fix it

Comment: @bibzuda7 did you check _all four_ lines of modified code?

Comment: I tried changing my code to exactly that, and 0.0 is still stored in reviews[0].price

Comment: @bibzuda7 please paste the print function. you dereferenced the pointers, right?